# Could a saturated drain field cause a toilet to back up?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

My drain field is over saturated from excessive rain, but before I figured that out, I replaced the wax ring on one toilet due to leakage from the bottom.  I also had to replace the flange and build up the flooring next to the pipe as it seemed to be deteriorated (gone).

I was having no issues with the second toilet. I had not flushed the toilets or run any water in the house for a week, and flushed the toilet that I had replaced the ring, heard gurgling in the shower, but water seeped out from the bottom of the second toilet.

I called a Septic Pumping company, explained the yard has excessive water in it, that I just recently had the septic tanks pumped and asked if that would alleviate the issues. To which they told me no, that I would have to wait until the yard dried out.

Will I have to replace the ring on the second toilet? Could there be issues with the existing drain field, which I assume is 32 years old as the house was built in 1982? I did not have any issues with drains or toilets flushing prior to the rains.

Answer (score 1):

As to backups into the sewage system, yes, a saturated drain field could cause that, no place for the grey-water to go.

Check around the inspection hole on the septic tank, should be a lot of leakage if that's the case as the tank will be full with no airspace if it has clogged outflow.

Excessive rain and drowned drainfields is a common wintertime issue here in Western Oregon. It's one reason our local city boundaries got massively redrawn to include a large area of the valley into the sewer district as the high water table and precipitation meant surface water was a health hazard.

Comment: I agree we do get flooded at times here in Oregon and that will cause backups. Also there is a chance that the line to the tank or line to the drain field has collapsed. Had this happen recently on the drain field side of the tank but this field was on a hill so it was not flooded. Found the failure at the first joint past the tank, dug it out and put a temp patch in will dig it up next summer and replace the old concrete pipe.